# What is this creature?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

[image: unidentified creature]

Since it has six legs, I believe it's some sort of insect, but I could be wrong.

I spotted it in my Central Texas backyard (Austin area). It was very slow and not at all skittish.

For size reference, it's standing on a 2x4. It was a good 3-5 inches long, not counting antennae.

Comment: I don't know anything about Texas insects, but it almost looks like a species of walking stick or other phasmatodea. I don't think I can get any closer than that.

Comment: I think you may be right. I looked into it a little more after posting this, and the nearest match I've found is the Two-Striped Walkingstick: http://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Two-Striped-Walkingstick. Thanks for your input!

Comment: yes walkingstick is what we would have called it in texas but i dont know if it fits the scientific classification...it sure is fat though

Comment: It is the Two-striped walking stick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Walkingsticks, like that in your photo, belong to the insect order Phasmida (also sometimes called Phasmatodea). The species in your photo belongs to the family Pseudophasmatidae. Texas has [two species documented](http://www.texasento.net/sticks.htm) for this family. One is [*Anisomorpha ferruginea*](http://phasmida.speciesfile.org/Common/basic/Taxa.aspx?TaxonNameID=1199469), commonly called the dark walkingstick or northern two-striped walkingstick.  The other species is [*Anisomorpha buprestoides*](http://phasmida.speciesfile.org/Common/basic/Taxa.aspx?TaxonNameID=1199463), commonly called Florida stick insect or two-striped walkingstick.

According to W.S. Blatchley's *Orthoptera of Northeastern America* (1920), [pg. 145](http://books.google.com/books?id=KcvwAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA780&lpg=PA780&dq=anisomorpha+buprestoides+vs+ferruginea&source=bl&ots=HhRc1bDOqD&sig=zX63hhHOqcKnY3MolnowBkvGDZI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xpz9U9jnL9S98QGFp4CwCA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwDg#v=onepage&q=anisomorpha%20buprestoides%20vs%20ferruginea&f=false), *A. ferruginea* has narrow stripes and is a bit shorter than *A. buprestoides*, which has broad stripes. Based on the appearance of the stripes in your photo, I'd say you have *A. buprestroides.*